# How to populate/display Punjabi alphabets one by one on Android

Tags: java, android, localization

How to populate/display Punjabi alphabets one by one on Android.

I have to display individual alphabets of a language one by one and then have to draw on it for learning purpose.

Comment: brute force method : just have images of all the alphabets, think you can try shape drawable to draw on scree , then may be you can compare these two images and give a score :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop from initial character to the last in Unicode chart.