# How to populate/display alphabets of a language one by one on Android

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to populate/display Punjabi alphabets one by one on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179083/how-to-populate-display-punjabi-alphabets-one-by-one-on-android)

How to populate/display alphabets of a language one by one on Android...

Can we read this from an external file and display it on android screen...if yes then how?

or any other way to do it...

Thanks 
Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

With the western alphabet it is easy. As you suggested yourself: look for a android tutorial on how to read from a text-file. And another on how to display text on the screen. Done.

If you want to display other alphabets, you might have to use UFT-16 or other text-formats for the text-file that shall contain the alphabet.

If you can't find any text-format that has the alphabet that you are looking for included, you have to do it as suggest in the "possible duplicate" mentioned in the comment to your question.